# How to get Name base on foreign key in Yii 1.6 admin view?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two tables Companies and Suppliers.Company ID is foreign key in Suppliers table.Suppose I have add one company in Companies table when i create the Supplier then I have also select the company Name.when I select the company like "Webdesignbestinclass" then CompanyID will save in Suppliers table.
When I admin view of Supplier then i have also CompanyID.Actually I want to get name of Company on Supplier admin view against the CompanyID ?

Some tell me How i can get it?

Comment: add some code also in post

Answer (score 1):

If you need a One-To_One relationships having foreigen

Define relation in 'Companies' model as :

```
public function relations()
{
  'supplier' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Supplier', 'company_id'),
}
```

In  'Supplier' model as:

```
public function relations()
{
  'company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Companies', 'supplier_id'),
}
```

I should be able to access the fields as:

```
$someCompany->supplier->field_x
 and
$someSupplier->company->field_y
```

you can find some explanation in this doc http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/

for obtain the field 'name' from companies model using the company relation defined in your supplier model relation function  you should use

```
array( 'name' => 'CompanyID', 'value' => '$data->company->name', ),
```

($data is the istance of the model in actual row of grid.)

Comment: please explain $someSupplier->company->field_y? As of my understanding company is relation and field_y is column name of table.......what is $someSupplier ?

Comment: $someSupplier is for you supplier Model .. company  (or companies) is the name you assign in the relation and field_y is a fileld con company model .. If is a one to one relations the element supplier belong (is related)  to a company .. hope is usefull ..

Comment: I have define In 'Supplier' model as:                                                      public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
   'company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'CompanyID'),
  );
 }

Comment: I have not defined on companies Model .. I have get company name on supplier view...here the code of get company name form company table    and it's working.array(
     'name' => 'CompanyID',
     'value' => '$data->company->getCompanyName()',
   ),  i have using the widget zii.widgets.grid.CGridView Problem is this I don't what is $data and how it's it provide me company name?

Comment: Instead of adding code in comment please update your question adding the code at the bottom and format properly.. (i can't read easily code in comment)

Comment: I have updated the Question but it's not align fine.I have defined the relation in both models..I have get company name in Supplier view..here the code array(
     'name' => 'CompanyID',
     'value' => '$data->company->CompanyName',
   ),                                                                                       I am using the widget zii.widgets.grid.CGridView Problem is this I don't what is $data and how it's it provide me company name?

Comment: Would you like to tell me about $data and how it's work in zii.widgets.grid.CGridView  ?

Comment: For gridview could be useful this http://www.bsourcecode.com/2012/12/how-to-handle-cgridview-in-yii/

Comment: Many Thanks scaisEdge

Comment: Your answer is right But when i am mark it as accepted then i am getting this message "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." When i will get reputation 15 I will must mark your answer.Thanks

Comment: Yes I got it and I marked your answer as right.Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103630/discussion-between-junaid-usmani-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 0):

**Option1** (Better if you access Parent/Child records more often)

You can definitely use relational active record, first check [Yii documentation for relational active record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

If you used gii to create your model after the foreign key was created then you should already have relations() created for you automatically.

Then you can do

```
$supplierId = 'your supplier id';

$supplier = Supplier::model()->findByPk($supplierId);

$companyName = $supplier->company->name;
```

If your supplier model already passed to your view then you can do

```
$model->company->name;
```

**Option2** (Faster)

```
$companyId = Your company ID ;

$company = Company::model()->findByPk($companyId);

$companyName = $company->name;
```

If your supplier model already passed to your view then you can do

```
$company = Company::model()->findByPk($model->company_id);

$companyName = $company->name;
```

Comment: I got the solution on first answer.You are also right..But i am using the zii.widgets.grid.CGridView I was display the name of company in zii.widgets.grid.CGridView .